# Installing a USB device manually on Win 8.1

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, drivers

I have been the not-so-proud owner of a Nokia Lumia 920 for over 2 weeks now. I am also in possession of two PCs, both running Windows 8.1.

I am unable to connect my phone to either PC in any way. Device manager keeps reporting my phone as `RM-821|Nokia Lumia 920`. I tried most of the solutions available on the web; here's what I've tried so far:

Everything listed on [this Microsoft KB2749484 article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2749484/en-us): searching for the driver on the internet and manually in `Windows` folder. I have also downloaded the driver itself (.cab file) from the Microsoft support page. I pointed to that folder as the location of the driver and Windows found nothing.

I tried installing the driver manually with `pkgmgr.exe`. Though since this is Windows 8.1 x64 Professional, received an error message that Pkgmgr is deprecated and cannot be used (`Error 0x80070002`).

I tried every single USB port on the laptop (Dell XPS 15 L502X) and desktop (Asus P4P800 Motherboard), and I didn't find any USB driver update. Both BIOSs are up to date. I have also tried rebooting with volume down while connected to the PC.

I am confident that this issue is not phone or cable related, as I tried plugging the phone into a friend's PC and it worked instantly. I tried chatting with a Microsoft help employee, who directed me to the Nokia homepage to search there. *sigh*

I have seen many people encountering this same issue.

Is there a way to install the .cab file manually in any other way?

Comment: Wow, this sucks. I'm a little confused though, what .cab file do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same problem a long time ago, and I found a solution.

All you have to do is switch off the device before plugging in the USB cable, and then switch it back on after plugging it in. Wait for about 5 minutes until the phone boots up.